# How to comment class path as classname in PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, class, phpstorm

I develop in Laravel. Laravel has class aliases, but PhpStorm alerts that class is not exists.

For example:

```
'aliases' => 
    array (
      'Debugbar' => 'Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Facade',
    ),
```

When I try to use `Debugbar::info();` I see `Undefined class 'Debugbar'`

I tried to define by `@property \Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade Debugbar`, but unfortunetly this is not works.

If it is possible I'd like to define this class globaly.

Comment: Hey please check here how to define a class in php :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Because it's an alias, PhpStorm doesn't know that what you are writing actually works.

Also, don't forget to add "use Debugbar"

Comment: perhaps the 'ide helper' package would be useful

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) is solved my problem. Thanks to lagbox.